# MySQL GROUP BY with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, union

I'm using `MySQL 5.5`. This is my query, the first part shows info about the company and it's vehicles, and the second part shows only company info.

I did the `UNION` part because some smallClients doesn't have any vehicles, and since at the first part it `join` with vehicles, those ones didn't appear.

What is the problem, some registers from the first and second part have the same smallClient, and since at the vehicles part I'm already showing company info, **I would like to group by, only if they are the same idClient and the same department, and numberPlate is not null (if it's null it's ok, I just want to remove those registers which are redundant cause info it's already showing in vehicle part).**

Some companies can have more than one number plate too, and they cannot be grouped, cause each number plate has it's own documentation (this query is smaller than the real one).

What results looks like now:

```
idClient  company          department    numberplate
3345      TONY FERGUSON    Commercial    null
3345      TONY FERGUSON    Financial     null
3345      TONY FERGUSON    Commercial    8453JVD
```

In this example, the first register should be gone, because this client has a numberPlate, and the register with the same department (first one), is redundant cause third registers shows the same.

Another example:

```
idClient  company          department               numberplate
1267      TERRY SL         Distribution - France    null
1267      TERRY SL         Distribución - France    6381JHZ
1267      TERRY SL         Forwarding UK            null
1267      TERRY SL         Forwarding UK            6381JHZ
```

In this case, first and third register should dissapear, hope I explained all propertly.

This is my query:

```
select  
    idClient as "IdClient",
    Company  as "Company",         
    if (Department is null, "", Department) as "Department",
    Numberplate,               
 from      
    (select
         sc.idClient as idclient,
         sc.businessname as company,     
         d.name as department,          
         v.numberplate as numberPlate,               
    from entity_type et
         join bigClient bc on bc.idClient=et.idClient
         join smallClient sc on sc.idclient=bc.idClientAssociated
         join clientVehicle cv on cv.idClientVehicle=sc.idClientVehicle
         join vehicle v on v.idVehicle=cv.idVehicle    
         join active_vehicle av on av.idEntityType=et.idEntityType and av.idClientVehicle=cv.idClientVehicle 
         left join department d on d.idDepartment=et.idDepartment   
         where bc.idClient=1234   
    UNION
    select 
         c.idClient as idclient,
         c.businessname as empresavehicle,      
         cd.name as departament,      
         null as matricula,          
        from entity_type et
         join bigClient bc on bc.idClient=et.idClient
         join smallClient sc on sc.idclient=bc.idClientAssociated
         join active_c ac on ac.idEntityType=et.idEntityType and ac.idBigClient=bc.idBigClient   
         left join department d on d.idDepartment=et.idDepartment        
         where bc.idClient=1234) t
    order by company,numberplate;
```

Comment: Is any company can have several different `numberplate` that not null?

Comment: Yes, it can happen that too, my bad for not specifying it.

Comment: So if we have result with 3 records, one of 3 is null and 2 other are different `numberplate`, we should remove only on null record, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, but we will have 4 results in this case, cause each numberPlate register will have it's "only company info" register.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I have the query and two different examples of it, what do I need more? I don't really get that downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function `count` as follows:

```
select * from
(select  
    idClient as "IdClient",
    Company  as "Company",         
    if (Department is null, "", Department) as "Department",
    Numberplate,
    count(Numberplate) over (partition by idClient,company,department) as cnt
  from
    .... rest of your query ....
) t
where cnt = 0 or (cnt>0 and Numberplate is not null)
```

Comment: That `over` part is giving me error, I think I don't have the proper version to do that. If i `select version();` the result is `5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in my SQL version? @Slava Rozhnev made an approach but I still need different registers for each number plate.

Answer (score 1):

The @Popeye solution should to work in MySQL 8.o or greater, for MySQL 5.x I can to advice next:

```
select  
    idclient as "IdClient",
    company  as "Company",         
    if (department is null, "", department) as "Department",
    group_concat(numberplate) as ,
 from      
    (select
         sc.idClient as idclient,
         sc.businessname as company,     
         d.name as department,          
         v.numberplate as numberplate,               
    from entity_type et
         join bigClient bc on bc.idClient=et.idClient
         join smallClient sc on sc.idclient=bc.idClientAssociated
         join clientVehicle cv on cv.idClientVehicle=sc.idClientVehicle
         join vehicle v on v.idVehicle=cv.idVehicle    
         join active_vehicle av on av.idEntityType=et.idEntityType and av.idClientVehicle=cv.idClientVehicle 
         left join department d on d.idDepartment=et.idDepartment   
         where bc.idClient=1234   
    UNION
    select 
         c.idClient as idclient,
         c.businessname as company,      
         cd.name as departament,      
         null as numberplate,          
        from entity_type et
         join bigClient bc on bc.idClient=et.idClient
         join smallClient sc on sc.idclient=bc.idClientAssociated
         join active_c ac on ac.idEntityType=et.idEntityType and ac.idBigClient=bc.idBigClient   
         left join department d on d.idDepartment=et.idDepartment        
         where bc.idClient=1234) t
    group by idClient, Company, Department
    order by company,numberplate;
```

this query should work with one limitation - in case different numberplate it return one concatinated string

Comment: Oh... So there isn't any way to have number plates separated? Cause each number plate has it's own documentation, I removed that part to make the query smaller.

Comment: Maybe we can do some type of `group by idClient, Company, Department` followed by some `having` condition, some kind of group by this only if there isn't more than one numer plate.